# How to handle result

Tags: go, neo4j

I'm working on a Go project that use a neo4j database. I don't fully understand how to handle results from my queries.

Under, this is my code that I managed to work but I would like to `return user` instead of `return user.email as email, user.pseudo as pseudo`. Here I have 2 return values, but what if I have more than 10 values to return... I'm not sure, I'm doing it properly.

```
data, err := session.ReadTransaction(func(tx neo4j.Transaction)(interface{}, error) {
        res, err := tx.Run(
            `match (user:User) where user.email = $email
            return user.email as email, user.pseudo as pseudo`,
            map[string]interface{}{"email": email})

            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            if res.Next() {
                if pseudo, found := res.Record().Get("pseudo"); found {
                    userData.Pseudo = pseudo.(string)
                }
                if email, found := res.Record().Get("email"); found {
                    userData.Email = email.(string)
                }

                return userData, nil
            }

            return nil, nil
    })
```

Thing is, when I return `user := res.Record().Values()[0]` instead of `res.Record().Get("something")`, I got an interface but I don't know how to extract the data specifying the id like `user.email`.
A `fmt.Printf("%t", user)` gives `&{%!t(*types.Node=&{0 [User] map[email:testman@mail.com pseudo:testman]})}`.

**UPDATE

```golang
data, err := session.ReadTransaction(func(tx neo4j.Transaction)(interface{}, error) {
        res, err := tx.Run(`MATCH (user:User) WHERE user.email = $email RETURN user`, map[string]interface{}{"email": email})

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        if res.Next() {         
            record, err := res.Single()

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", err.Error())
                return nil, err
            }

            userRecord, found := record.Get("user")

            if !found {
                return nil, errors.New("User not found")
            }

            userAttributes := userRecord.(map[string]interface{})
            userData.Email = userAttributes["email"].(string)

            return userData, nil
        }

        return nil, nil
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome!
If you query ends with `RETURN user` and because it seems you want a single result, you can write:

```golang
    record, err := res.Single()
    // [...] check err
    userRecord, err := record.Get("user")
    // [...] check err
    userAttributes := userRecord.(dbtype.Node).Props // 1st cast record into node and extract properties
    userData.pseudo := userAttributes["pseudo"].(string) // then cast each property value to expected type 
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks @fbiville, actually, if I'm not mistaken, I did follow your great videos "realworld.io backend with the Neo4j Golang"! But I can't do res.Single(), the function Single() seems to be unavailable... I do have Consume, Next, Err, Keys... but not this one nor Collect..

Comment: Are you using the Go driver v4?
In your `go.mod`, it should look like: `github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/v4 v4.2.1`.
The import in your source code should be `"github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/v4/neo4j"`.

Comment: Oh so sorry I wasn't. Now that I use v4, I have access to those functions.. BUT ```res.Single()``` returns an error ```Result contains no more records```. Which is weird because when I print my res.Record(), I do have records  ```{%!s(int64=0) [User] map[email:testman@mail.com pseudo:testman]}```

Comment: can you update the initial code snippet so that I can have a look?

Comment: I did update my original post. In the meantime, I tried to move my ```res.Single()``` before the if statement ```res.Next()``` and it works! However when I cast the Node into map it returns this error ```interface {} is dbtype.Node, not map[string]interface {}```.
printing my userRecord I get this object ```{%!s(int64=0) [User] map[email:testman@mail.com pseudo:testman]}```

Comment: indeed, you should not call Next when using Single.
Let me check with the cast error.

Comment: The error makes sense, you indeed return a node, not a map. Let me update my answer.

Comment: thank you so much! Now I have a better understanding how to handle my data & cast type of interfaces.